# RDF modelling of list of name elements

Tags: rdf, ontology, modeling, vcf-vcard, foaf

I am investigating transitioning an application to use RDF. One roadblock is how this application models names of persons. It supports straight-forward full names as a single string, but also supports decomposed names, e.g. person X has given name *Frens* followed by a second given name *Jan* followed by the family name *Rumph*.

The data structure is something like:

```java
enum Role {
   ...
   GIVEN_NAME,
   FAMILY_NAME,
   ...
}

record NameElement(role: Role, value: String) {}

record AnnotatedName(NameElement... elements) {}
```

in order to be instantiated like:

```java
var name = new AnnotatedName(
    new NameElement(GIVEN_NAME, "Frens"),
    new NameElement(GIVEN_NAME, "Jan"),
    new NameElement(FAMILY_NAME, "de Vries")
);
```

This allows reconstruction of the name into a string while at the same time expressing the components of the name. So it captures the roles of the elements of a name (e.g. given names, family names) *as well as* their order (given names aren't first everywhere). Also, it allows expressing multiple names. E.g. in multiple languages / scripts. Or even aliases used in different areas of the world.

I have toyed around with some RDF constructs, but none are really satisfactory:

```
# list of strings misusing data types as tags
:frens :name ( "Frens"^^:givenName "Jan"^^:givenName "de Vries"^^:familyName ) .

# list of blank nodes
:frens :name ( [ :givenName "Frens" ]
               [ :givenName "Jan" ]
               [ :familyName "de Vries" ] ) .

# single blank node with unordered 'elements'
:frens :name [ a           :AnnotatedPersonName ;
               :fullName   "Frens Jan de Vries" ;
               :givenName  "Frens" ;
               :givenName  "Jan" ;
               :familyName "de Vries" ] .
```

---

**Existing ontologies for HD names?**
Is there an existing ontology that covers such 'high fidelity'? FOAF and vcard have some relevant properties, but aren't able to capture this level of semantics.

**Lists?** One major 'blocker' in migrating this approach to RDF is the notion of order that is used. If at all possible, I'd like to stay away from the List / Container swamp in RDF land ...

Comment: Is the order actually that important? You can store any number of given names and family names, a preferred name and the full name. Names usually don't have semantics that warrant this kind of decomposition.

Comment: I'm working with use cases e.g. in Spain where decomposing multiple last names and their order is relevant. Also there are "naming traditions" where people have many given names but are known colloquially by a much shorter 'first name'. Finally there is a matter of the order of family and given names that may differ from culture to culture (e.g. family names first in China versus last in cultures with EU roots).

Splitting strings may work to some extent, but is error prone.
 
(sorry for the late response, missed the notification)

Comment: The variety of these naming "schemes" is precisely why I don't think making the composition method or algorithm part of the data is a good idea. A person has many names for many purposes, i.e. the full legal name, a preferred full name, name for listings, full surname, preferred given/surname, any given/surname, a family name, pseudonyms, nicknames, preferred addressing name, honorifics, titles etc. Why is the fact that the full name of a person is `preferred given name + other given names + surname` relevant to you? Just store the full name.

Comment: Plus there are (or may be) languages where you cannot derive the full name from *any* of its components by a simple concatenation, in any order. Inflection, shortenings, other strange rules... Instead, if you know one of the names, just store it in the data; if you don't know it when you need it, try to guess it (based on nationality, language etc.) but don't store the guessed form. If you know the components *and* the order in which they form another name *and* the behaviour of the target language, just store the components and the result; the rest is too complex to describe anyway.

Comment: Yes, you might end up with redundancy in the data, but then we are discussing just compression, not the semantics. There are of course other more complicated details, like different versions of a name in different langugaes etc. I am also afraid I don't know any particular ontology that covers all the different names, but you can create your own based on your intentions. I just don't think of a name as of a list of components, in general.

Comment: In the context I raised the question in, separating components of a name is a) available (e.g. Spanish with fields like last name #1 and last name #2) and b) useful since the system uses services with such notions. It is however just one of the many cases. If it were just for display purposes or (basic text) search I would just stick the name in a string. I am fully aware that capturing every nuance is impossible.

Comment: I was hoping to reach a middle ground between a mess of extending the data model for every use case on our path and going low fidelity with just a full name string. (the later not really an option because of the need to call external services on a higher level of fidelity and also it can really help in entity disambiguation).